# Issue in consuming Restful webserive using apache camel reslet framework

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, restlet, jbossfuse

I have a Camel Project which runs in 8080 port to consume external restful web service which is a SpringBoot project which runs in port 8082, toproduce employee information based on the end point call. Here I'm trying to consume ResetFul webservice using Apache Camel Restlet. While consuming the webservice every alternative call is failing.

```
Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:8082/employeeController/getEmployeeDetails/12?wsdl with statusCode: 400 /n responseBody:<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>Your browser sent an invalid request.</body></html>

This is the error i'm getting on every alternative call. 

Restlet code to consume which is written inside Camel Context.

<to id="getEmployeeDetails" pattern="InOut" uri="restlet:http://localhost:8082/employeeManager/getEmployeeDetails/{employeeId}?restletMethod=GET"/>

SpringBoot code which produces webservice,

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="employeeController")
public class EmployeeController{

@RequestMapping(value="/getEmployeeDetails/{employeeId}", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable("employeeId") int employeeId) {
//getting the employee information from DB
}
}

The Camel Resetlet dependency added in pom.xml is

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.1</version>
</dependency>> 

Do i need add any other maven dependency in order to work for every endpoint call? Could you please help me here.
```

Comment: It's not a great idea to mix spring mvc and camel restlet within the same project.

Comment: Both are independent projects.

Comment: Can you please share a github project simulating the same?

Comment: I got the solution for this. The issue was from the source system its a SOAP call and to target system its a rest call. What I did is I removed the SOAP headers before calling external rest service and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to consume *Restlet Resources* is to use the **Restlet HTTP Client**:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

With a code similar to this:

```
Component c = new Component();
Client client = c.getClients().add(Protocol.HTTP);
client.getContext().getParameters().add ( "socketTimeout", "1000" );
Response resp = client.handle(new Request(Method.GET, "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"));
System.out.println("Output: " + resp.getEntity().getText());
```